# ShaderLab. Ошибка компиляции при попытке добавить Color в Properties

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

Доброго времени суток.

Пишу простой шейдер для Unity:

```
Shader "MyShaders/boring_shader" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white"
        _MyColor("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { 
            "PreviewType"="Plane" 
            "Queue" = "Transparent"
        } 
        Pass {
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MyColor;

            struct ModelVertex {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct V2f {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            V2f vert(ModelVertex v) {
                V2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            float4 frag(V2f i) : SV_Target {
                float4 color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                color.r = i.uv.x;
                color.g = i.uv.y;
                return color;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

После добавления строк `_MyColor("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)` и `float4 _MyColor;` получаю ошибку Shader error in 'boring_shader2': Parse error: syntax error, unexpected TVAL_ID at line 4. Ни как не могу понят в чем дело.

Пожалуйста, объясните в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После  значения по умолчанию для текстуры (в моем случае это "white") - следовало поставить пустые фигурные скобки.